# Build a C++ program in Clion: "Target not found"

Tags: c++, ide, clion

I have searched some solutions online and on Stackoverflow but could not found one that suits mine. The code below is the `CMakeList.txt` of `vector` file. `vector` file is a sub-file of the parent file `DSA`, in which there are also `main.cpp` and `CMakeList.txt`, but I do not believe they are relevant.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(vector)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    copy_assignment.h
    copy_constructor.h
    main.cpp
    traverse_funcs.h
    vector.h
    vector_bin_search_a.h
    vector_bin_search_b.h
    vector_bin_search_c.h
    vector_bracket.h
    vector_bubble.h
    vector_bubblesort.h
    vector_deduplicate.h
    vector_disordered.h
    vector_expand.h
    vector_fib_search_a.h
    vector_find.h
    vector_insert.h
    vector_merge.h
    vector_mergesort.h
    vector_permute.h
    vector_remove.h
    vector_removeinternal.h
    vector_shrink.h
    vector_traverse.h
    vector_uniquify.h
    vector_unsort.h)

add_executable(vector ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

main.cpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "vector.h"
#include "vector_permute.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << foo.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the configuration window. I have added `add_executable(vector ${SOURCE_FILES})` into C makelist but it still does not work, what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the add_subdirectory command.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

> Add a subdirectory to the build.
>
> add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir]
>                    [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL])
>
> Add a subdirectory to the build. The source_dir specifies the
>   directory in which the source CMakeLists.txt and code files are
>   located. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to
>   the current directory (the typical usage), but it may also be an
>   absolute path. The binary_dir specifies the directory in which to
>   place the output files. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated
>   with respect to the current output directory, but it may also be an
>   absolute path. If binary_dir is not specified, the value of
>   source_dir, before expanding any relative path, will be used (the
>   typical usage). The CMakeLists.txt file in the specified source
>   directory will be processed immediately by CMake before processing in
>   the current input file continues beyond this command.

CLion doesn't know to look for your other CMakeLists.txt file without this added to the top level CMakeLists.txt file that is defining your DSA project.

Answer (score 0):

CMakeLists.txt (with an s) maybe?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: In contrast to the other reviewers, I think this is actually an attempt at answering the question. Please elaborate a bit more on it; if the problem is indeed caused by the typo, this answer would be valid.

Comment: Hi crujose you are right, I forgot to add an "s" in the question, however, it's right in the IDE. And the solution is that add_subdirectory() command.